# Why isn't the upper disc removed after achieving equilibrium in Lee charlton method?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

**The experiment **:- [image]

We know  in lee charlton's method there are two discs the in between insulating disc results in in a gradient of temperature between the two discs. Now when the insulating material is removed the two disks are are made contact so that they receive in an equilibrium in temperature which is more than the equilibrium temperature (of the bottom disc). Now the question in my mind is that why does the upper disc has to be there after the 10 degrees temperature of the lower disc is incremented ;after all the mass which are using in the formula is for just Lee's disc not for the both disc combined. Now I am in a confusion the mass of the upper disc is also added when we are doing it experimentally but In theoretical you're saying that the mass is just for the least disc please clarify my confusion.

Comment: I don’t think most of us are familiar with Lee and Charlton, who were apparently two different people, not someone named Lee Charlton.

Comment: Should I explain the experiment?

Comment: Yes, I think that would make your question clearer. I can’t currently understand it.

Comment: A diagram would also be useful. Please.

Comment: I am unable to post an image I don't know why.